# How to define the Actions element of the XML document

Tags: xml, xsd

I am a beginner in XML, I want to know how to define the Actions element of the XML document by creating a complex XSD custom type that can check the Actions element ?
Can you help to validate my both xml with my XSD Schema ?
I know I need to use this structure. <xs:complexType name="ActionsType" > but I can't get my xml to validate with my xsd.

Thank in advance.

This is my XML 1

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Reference>ADAMS-20011127121040988PST</Reference>
    <Actions>
        <Action> 
            <User>SCOTT TIGER</User> 
            <Date>2021-05-15</Date>
        </Action> 
        <Reject/>
        <Requestor>Julie P. Adams</Requestor> 
        <CostCenter>R20</CostCenter> 
        <ShippingInstructions>
            <name>Julie P. Adams</name>
  
            <address>300 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065</address> 
            <telephone>650 506 7300</telephone>
  
        </ShippingInstructions> 
        <SpecialInstructions>Ground</SpecialInstructions> 
        <LineItems>
  
            <LineItem ItemNumber="1">
  
                <Description>The Ruling Class</Description>
  
                <Part Id="715515012423" UnitPrice="39.95" Quantity="2"/>
  
            </LineItem>
  
            <LineItem ItemNumber="2">
  
                <Description>Diabolique</Description>
  
                <Part Id="037429135020" UnitPrice="29.95" Quantity="3"/> </LineItem>
  
            <LineItem ItemNumber="3">
  
                <Description>8 1/2</Description>
  
                <Part Id="037429135624" UnitPrice="39.95" Quantity="4"/> </LineItem>
  
        </LineItems> 
  
    </Actions>
  
  
</PurchaseOrder>
```

My Second Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PurchaseOrder>
    <Reference>BILLY-20021127121040988PST</Reference>
    <Actions>
        <Action> 
            <User>SCOTT TIGER</User> 
            <Date>2021-05-11</Date>
        </Action> 
        <Action> 
            <User>SCOTT TIGER</User> 
            <Date>2021-05-13</Date>
        </Action> 
        <Action> 
            <User>SCOTT TIGER</User> 
            <Date>2021-05-15</Date>
        </Action> 
        <Reject>
            <Date>2021-05-15</Date>
            <Comment>After 3 reminders, no answer from the requestor. The purchase order is rejected.</Comment>
            <User>SCOTT TIGER</User> 
        </Reject>
        <Requestor>Jean BILLY</Requestor> 
        <CostCenter>4310</CostCenter> 
        <ShippingInstructions>
            <name>Julie P. Adams</name>

            <address>300 Oracle Parkway, Redwood Shores, CA 94065</address> 
            <telephone>650 506 7300</telephone>

        </ShippingInstructions> 
        <SpecialInstructions>Ground</SpecialInstructions> 
        <LineItems>

            <LineItem ItemNumber="1">

                <Description>Rent car</Description>

                <Part Id="715515012423" UnitPrice="1258025436.95" Quantity="2"/>

            </LineItem>

        </LineItems> 

    </Actions>
    
    
</PurchaseOrder>
```

and my XSD

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="PurchaseOrder">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Reference"/>
            <xs:element ref="Actions"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="PurchaseOrder" type="PurchaseOrder"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Reference" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Reference" type="Reference"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Actions">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Action"/>
            <xs:element ref="Reject"/>
            <xs:element ref="Requestor"/>
            <xs:element ref="CostCenter"/>
            <xs:element ref="ShippingInstructions"/>
            <xs:element ref="SpecialInstructions"/>
            <xs:element ref="LineItems"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Actions" type="Actions"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Action">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="User"/>
            <xs:element ref="Date"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Action" type="Action"/>
    <xs:complexType name="User" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="User" type="User"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Date" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Date" type="Date"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Reject">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Date"/>
            <xs:element ref="Comment"/>
            <xs:element ref="User"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Reject" type="Reject"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Requestor" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Requestor" type="Requestor"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CostCenter" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="CostCenter" type="CostCenter"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ShippingInstructions">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="address"/>
            <xs:element ref="telephone"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="ShippingInstructions" type="ShippingInstructions"/>
    <xs:complexType name="name" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="name" type="name"/>
    <xs:complexType name="address" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="address" type="address"/>
    <xs:complexType name="telephone" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="telephone" type="telephone"/>
    <xs:complexType name="SpecialInstructions" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="SpecialInstructions" type="SpecialInstructions"/>
    <xs:complexType name="LineItems">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="LineItem"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="LineItems" type="LineItems"/>
    <xs:complexType name="LineItem">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="Description"/>
            <xs:element ref="Part"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="ItemNumber" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="LineItem" type="LineItem"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Description" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Description" type="Description"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Part" mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Quantity" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="UnitPrice" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Part" type="Part"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Comment" mixed="true"/>
    <xs:element name="Comment" type="Comment"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your XML is given. You can try the following XSD for your XML.

You can adjust (fine tune) its facets for your needs.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="PurchaseOrder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Reference"/>
        <xs:element ref="Actions"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Reference" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Actions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Action"/>
        <xs:element ref="Reject"/>
        <xs:element ref="Requestor"/>
        <xs:element ref="CostCenter"/>
        <xs:element ref="ShippingInstructions"/>
        <xs:element ref="SpecialInstructions"/>
        <xs:element ref="LineItems"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Action">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="User"/>
        <xs:element ref="Date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Reject">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Date" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="Comment" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="User" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Requestor" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="CostCenter" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="ShippingInstructions">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
        <xs:element ref="telephone"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="telephone" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="SpecialInstructions" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="LineItems">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="LineItem" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="LineItem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Description"/>
        <xs:element ref="Part"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="ItemNumber" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Part">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="Quantity" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute name="UnitPrice" use="required" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="User" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot to mention that I have two XMLs and I would like to validate both.  Still with the possibility to check the action element. I encounter this error : element Action: Schemas validity error : Element 'Action': This element is not expected. Expected is ( Reject ).
BC2.xml fails to validate

Comment: @KyrianKyky, it is not clear what is your objective. The provided XML is valid against the XSD in the answer.

Comment: indeed it validates well my first xml except that I have two xml with a slight difference on an element <reject>. Sorry I am beginner in XML

Comment: @KyrianKyky, I updated the XSD in the answer. Now both XML files are valid against the XSD.

Comment: It works perfectly, it validates my two xml. however I would like to be able to associate an actionTypes to my Actions element for the two XML with their reject elements Thank you so much